# How i can set the span id text which is within a "a" element

Tags: javascript, jquery

***HTML***

```
 <a href="#" id="popp" name="popo" class="tooltipLink">
  <img  src="images/information.png" alt="info" />
  <span  class="tipp"></span>
 </a>
```

***jQuery***

```
var text = blah;
$('#popo span').text(text);
```

The text is not setting...I am doing something wrong..?

Comment: should be `#popp span` if that is not typo.

Answer (score 2):

Typo and lack of quotes.. this will work:

```
var text = "blah";
$('#popp span').text(text);
```

First, by having this: `var text = blah;` you assigned the text as undefined variable and second you used the name instead of the ID of the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your selector matches a span inside the element with the id 'popo', which does not exist (popp != popo).
2. You are trying to assign the value of `text` which is a copy of `blah` which is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant:

```
var text = 'blah';
$('#popp span').text(text);
```

as seen in this [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v9a8K/).

Things to notice:

- `blah` is wrapped inside quotes as it represents a string
- use `#popp` instead of `#popo` as id selector

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#popp span.tipp').text(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var text = "blah";
$('#popp span').text(text);
```